# How to create GUI with text links and tabs

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a UI like http://www.ndtv.com/static/images/iphone/motorola_droid.jpg, where extra links are below the tabs. How can we achieve this?

I already made tabs but not understanding how to add this text view with this.

Comment: Have you started or tried doing mock layouts yet? Maybe it would be better to experiment and try to achieve what you want and then post particular problems you run into.  Of course you would want a `TabHost`, and then the tab contents would probably be a `RelativeLayout` containing the links and the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like the XML below.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <TabHost 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/background_retinav2">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:id="@+id/rl_1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <HorizontalScrollView
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:id="@+id/gv"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:scrollbars="none"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:foregroundGravity="bottom">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="Top Stories"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:text="News"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/san_tag"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    </LinearLayout>
                </HorizontalScrollView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <WebView android:id="@+id/content_movies"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:listSelector="@color/gray"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TabHost>
```

Inside the scrollview, place the text view what you need, so it has your title menus.
For more about TabHost, refer to the URL http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Tabs1.html.